# where can I get a true 3/4" x 3/4" molding?

Tags: wood, woodworking, hardwood-floor

I need to replace a 1 foot and a 3 foot section of 3/4"x3/4" true sized shoe quarter round molding from a very old house.  Found some claimed to be 3/4 but it was actual 3/4"x1/2".

Where can I find the true sized molding or how can I make it?

Thanks

Comment: You need simply quarter round. When you use the term "shoe" the size you got is shoe mold. Quarter round nowadays is 11/16"X11/16". you may be lucky enough to find it 3/4"X3/4", but don't use the term shoe or shoe mold in your description.

Comment: https://www.bobvila.com/articles/shoe-molding/ there is a picture there showing
shoe molding that appears to be 1/2"x3/4" contrasted with a simple 3/4"x3/4"
round.

https://empire-s3-production.bobvila.com/articles/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Shoe_Molding_vs_Quarter_Round.jpg i


Finishing trim comes in two different shapes: shoe molding vs. quarter round.

... While quarter-round can be
installed along the bottom of baseboard, trim carpenters and homeowners tend to
prefer the sleeker look of shoe molding, which is taller and narrower than its
curved counterpart.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to make it you'll need a router and a corner round over bit with a 3/4" radius.

For that small amount of material you are likely better off just looking up woodworking and calling around to find out how much someone will charge to get it custom made.  It is a pretty simple job and any wood working shop will have the tools to do it.

Comment: Also, a lumber yard (not a big box store) _might_ have some or be willing to make some for you. If not, they'll know some woodworkers in the area who would be willing to do so.